# DynamoDB : Unable to install due to Log4j2 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, jar, amazon-dynamodb, log4j2

I am new to the AWS stack. I am trying to install DynamoDB locally according to the instructions mentioned in their [website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

I tried installing via docker-compose. However I was getting the following error

```
Creating dynamodb-local ... done
Attaching to dynamodb-local
dynamodb-local    | Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
dynamodb-local    | Port:       8000
dynamodb-local    | InMemory:   true
dynamodb-local    | DbPath:     null
dynamodb-local    | SharedDb:   false
dynamodb-local    | shouldDelayTransientStatuses:       false
dynamodb-local    | CorsParams: *
dynamodb-local    |
dynamodb-local    | ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

I tried installing via jar file. However, I was getting the same error

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:       false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:       true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams:     *

ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

I am trying to install on Windows 10 system with WSL2. Is there any compatibility issue between DynamoDB and WSL2 which is causing this error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That statement is misleading: it is just saying that there is no Log4j configuration available so there won't be any logging; the installation may have been successful. Try connecting to the local instance on port 8000 using the aws cli, or your own application to see if it works.

Comment: If you'd like to, you can try creating a simple log4j conf file that outputs everything to console (see: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) and pass that into the jar with something like `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`